# Why is MANOVA robust to non normality?

Tags: robust, manova

In *Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis*, Wichern and Johnson state that "with reasonably large samples, the MANOVA tests of means are rather robust to nonnormality". Why is that?

Comment: Similar Q:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508710/challenging-robustness-to-violations-of-multivariate-normality