# Challenging robustness to violations of multivariate normality

Tags: multivariate-analysis, statistical-power, normality-assumption, robust, manova

I am generating multivariate normal (MVN) data and evaluating power of MANOVA in R. For instance, I simulate a factor A with two levels, and obtain $\boldsymbol{y}_{A_1} \sim MVN(\boldsymbol{\mu_1}, \Sigma)$ for the first level and $\boldsymbol{y}_{A_2} \sim MVN(\boldsymbol{\mu_2}, \Sigma)$ for the second level. For simplicity, let's consider $\Sigma = \rm{I}$, $\boldsymbol{\mu_1} = \boldsymbol{0}$, and $\boldsymbol{\mu_2} = \boldsymbol{\delta}$. Thus, with $\boldsymbol{\delta}$ I can control the difference in multivariate means and therefore measure power at different points.

However, when simulating multivariate data from any other distribution (e.g. via a Gaussian copula with uniform marginals, with any given correlation structure) I obtain really similar power estimates.

I was wondering which scenario (regarding non-normality) would be good to challenge the robustness of MANOVA (I am leaving heteroskedasticity out from this analysis on purpose, as it does affect dramatically MANOVA type I error).